# MongoDB add an autoincrement

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu

Looking to be able to have an autoincrementing value in my React application using MongoDB in my back-end using NodeJS running on a Ubuntu server.

The docs that I have found refer to setting up a Trigger.  The docs look like they are referencing Mongo Atlas.  Since I am not using Atlas, I am looking for an alternative solution.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: see [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/), with that you can have a collection counter, with 1 document, that you update and get the new value in atomic way before anyone could change it, set new option to true.

Comment: So db trigger is not needed as described in mongo docs?  Is this to manually increment value in counter collection?  How does this prevent other user from incrementing at the same time?  Do you know of any example code?  Thanks

Comment: its atomic, query modifies the counter(inc for example) and you get the new value(before anyone else can change it), so its not possible 2 queries to return the same value.

Comment: My intention is to use the autoincrement counter as a unique ID for documents in another collection. Would I then have to make two separate database calls? One for the increment and another to create the new document in the other collection? Or can it be combined somehow?

Comment: yes 2 calls, 1 to get the unique id, and then to insert that new document with that id
findAndModify can assure you that no one can take this id more that 1 time, maybe there is another better way but this i think is fine.If you want like 20 ids, increament by 20, it will be fine. (i mean no need to do it 1 call/id)

Comment: I am using Mongoose. findAndModify doesn't exist.  Instead I have tried findOneAndUpdate, but when I do so, it's just returning null.  My function call is: const getJobSequence = async (sequenceName) => {
  let result = await jobCounters.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: "jobNo" },
    { $inc: { seq: 1 } },
    { new: true }
  );
  return result;
};

Comment: findOneAndUpdate can do the same,inside a findAndModify command will be called anyways,collection should start from  `[{"jobNo" : 0}]`  have only 1 document with 1 field,
and you `.findOneAndUpdate( {}, { $inc: { jobNo: 1 } }, { new: true } )`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237018/discussion-between-d-barman-and-takis).